# Converting a regular date to a Hebrew date on IntelliJ using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, date, intellij-idea

I have a regular date format which I want to convert to a Hebrew date on a Kotlin program on IntelliJ. I later need to display the date using Compos on Windows. The simple code I have up to now is:

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yy")
var date = LocalDate.parse("31.11.15", formatter)
println("The date is: ${date.format(formatter)}")
println("The day is: ${date.dayOfMonth}, the Month is: ${date.month}, the year is: ${date.year}")
```

but now I need to convert the date to a Hebrew date and I haven't found any API to do this, so I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://kosherjava.com/zmanim-project/. The library is written on Java but you can use it from Kotlin.

Comment: I have seen this library before it's much too heavy for what I need. You have to know the time and location and other data. I'm looking for something light, that I can take any date from the past, and translate it into a  Hebrew date.